What's the difference between "burn something down" and "burn down something"
I came across a saying that "I should have burned this place down when I had a chance".
Why don't they use "burned down this place"?
Are these two clusters the same?

You can find about this phrasal verb in Oxford Dictionary online https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/burn-down?q=burn+down

In your context the two phrases mean the same, it's just a matter of choice by the writer / speaker. This is an example of English having a somewhat flexible word order.
Note that you could substitute "whilst" for "when" with little change in meaning except "whilst" implies an ongoing period of time (whilst I was employed / studied /  stayed there) and "when" is more like a single period of time (minute, hour, day, visit).

Why not  "while"?

@KateBunting Yes, that works as well.

English has phrasal verbs that are separable and others that are non-seperable.
See the explanation and examples at British Council grammar
For example: burn down is seperable
burn the house down
burn down the house
With the pronoun:
burn it down

More to the point, tt's optionally separable. There are one or two transitive multi-word verbs that are obligatorily separable.

@EdwinAshworth I think I made that clear: burn the house down versus burn down the house. I also said there were separable and non-separables ones.
